# using stream api to find largest directories

Tags: java, java-8

i have a list of FileCriteria. FileCriteria is:

```
public class FileCriteria {

  private final Path path;
  private final long size;

  public FileCriteria(Path path, long size) {
    this.path = path;
    this.size = size;       
  }

  public Path getPath() {
    return path;
  }

  public Path getParentPath() {
    return path.getParent() == null ? Paths.get("") : path.getParent();
  }

  public long getSize() {
    return size;
  }
}
```

The list contains FileCriteria of every file and directory of
a directory, in other words a complete file tree.
Now i need to find the directories with the largest files in it (the sum of the size of all files in it), not including subdirectories, they count as file size 0.

My Stream API based solution is this:

```
List<FileCriteria> fileCriterias = ...

Map<Path, Long> dirToSize = fileCriterias.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(FileCriteria::getParentPath, summingLong(FileCriteria::getSize)));

List<Path> largestDirs = dirToSize.keySet().stream()
    .sorted((p1, p2) -> -Long.compare(dirToSize.get(p1), dirToSize.get(p2)))
    .limit(10)
    .collect(toList());
```

Can this be simplified in some way? i mean from a readabilty point of view.

The hint of Prometheus leads to the following improvement:

```
Map<Path, Long> dirToSize = fileCriterias.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(FileCriteria::getParentPath, summingLong(FileCriteria::getSize)));

List<Path> largestDirs = dirToSize.keySet().stream()
  .sorted(comparing(dirToSize::get).reversed())
  .limit(10)
  .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fairly simple already.
You could use comparing() (natural order) together with reversed() to sort in descending order.

```
List<Path> largestDirs = dirToSize.keySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparing(dirToSize::get).reversed())
    .limit(10)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: ah yes using comparing is more concise! As a side note the getSize invocation is not needed, cause the map already contains
the values as Long. The OP is updated...

Comment: You are right, not sure how I missed that. That also makes the function unnecessary. Fixed.

Comment: When streaming over a map, it’s discouraged to perform a lookup for each element as it’s inefficient. Just stream over the elements rather than over the keys: `dirToSize.entrySet().stream()
.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
.limit(10).map(Map.Entry::getKey)
.collect(toList())`